# What is the construction of this filter

Tags: filter-design

I have built a resonance filter using the code from [here](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/Impulse_Tracker#IT214_sample_compression) I would like to know what the construction of this filter is. I believe it is an IIR and that it is probably a second order/two pole filter but that is as far as my knowledge goes.

My Code:

````
public class ItFilter implements ISimpleFilter {

    // static resonance table
    public static final float[] RESONANCE_TABLE = {//removed for simplicity};

    // instance variables
    private double cutoffFrequency;
    private byte resonance;
    private double sampleRate;
    private double valueZero;
    private double valueOne;
    private double cutoffAmount;
    private double resonanceAmount;
    private double a, b, c, d, e;
    private boolean highPass;
    private double highPassValue;

    // constructor
    public ItFilter(double cutoffFrequency, double sampleRate, byte resonance,
            boolean highPass) {
        this.cutoffFrequency = cutoffFrequency;
        if (this.cutoffFrequency > sampleRate / 2) {
            this.cutoffFrequency = sampleRate / 2;
        }
        this.cutoffFrequency = cutoffFrequency;
        this.sampleRate = sampleRate;
        this.resonance = resonance;
        this.highPass = highPass;
        cutoffAmount = 2.0 * Math.PI * this.cutoffFrequency / this.sampleRate;
        resonanceAmount = RESONANCE_TABLE[this.resonance];
        d = resonanceAmount * cutoffAmount + resonanceAmount - 1.0;
        e = cutoffAmount * cutoffAmount;
        a = 1.0 / (1.0 + d + e);
        if (highPass) {
            a = 1.0 - a;
        }
        b = (d + 2 * e) / (1.0 + d + e);
        c = (-e) / (1.0 + d + e);
        highPassValue = (highPass) ? 1.0 : 0;
        valueZero = 0;
        valueOne = 0;
    }

    // setters
    @Override
    public void setCutoff(double cutoffFrequency) {
        this.cutoffFrequency = cutoffFrequency;
        if (this.cutoffFrequency > sampleRate / 2) {
            this.cutoffFrequency = sampleRate / 2;
        }
        cutoffAmount = sampleRate / (2.0 * Math.PI * this.cutoffFrequency);
        d = resonanceAmount * cutoffAmount + resonanceAmount - 1.0;
        e = cutoffAmount * cutoffAmount;
        a = 1.0 / (1.0 + d + e);
        if (highPass) {
            a = 1.0 - a;
        }
        b = (d + 2 * e) / (1.0 + d + e);
        c = (-e) / (1.0 + d + e);
    }

    // low pass filter
    @Override
    public double filter(double point) {

        double filteredValue, returnValue;

        filteredValue = a * point + b * valueZero + c * valueOne;

        // normalise filteredValue
        filteredValue = (filteredValue > 1) ? 1 : filteredValue;
        filteredValue = (filteredValue < -1) ? -1 : filteredValue;

        valueOne = valueZero;
        valueZero = filteredValue - (point * highPassValue);

        returnValue = filteredValue;

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This beginning of this answer is a reformatting of [Resonant filters](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/Impulse_Tracker#IT214_sample_compression).

$$K[n] = aS[n] + bK[n-1] + cK[n-2]$$

where:

$K[n]$ is the output value at time n
$S[n]$ is the input value at time n

$a = \frac{1}{1+d+e}$
$b = \frac{d+2e}{1+d+e}$
$c = -\frac{e}{1+d+e}$

$d = 2pr+2p-1$
$e = r^2$

$r = \text{playback_frequency} \frac{2.0\cdot\pi\cdot110.0\cdot(2.0^{0.25})}{2^{\text{cutoff}/24.0}}$
$p = 10^{(-\text{resonance}\cdot24.0)/(128.0\cdot20.0)}$

The z-transform of the filter is:
$$K(z) = aS(z) + bK(z)z^{-1} + cK(z)z^{-2}$$

Yielding the transfer function:
$$K(z) - bK(z)z^{-1} - cK(z)z^{-2} = aS(z)$$
$$K(z)\frac{1}{a}\left[1 - bz^{-1} - cz^{-2}\right] = S(z)$$
$$H(z) = \frac{K(z)}{S(z)} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}\left[1 - bz^{-1} - cz^{-2}\right]} = \frac{a}{1 - bz^{-1} - cz^{-2}}$$

This is indeed a 2-pole, second order filter, infinite impulse response (IIR) filter.  The specifics of its filtering characteristics will be dependent on the other input paramaters.

Comment: Thanks for that, now is there a way to turn this into a band pass and band limit filter? Also, how can I convert it into a 3 or more pole filter?